# Command to import multiple files from Cloud Storage into BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud, gsutil

I've figured that this command lists paths to all files:

```
gsutil ls "gs://bucket/foldername/*.csv"
```

This command imports a file to BQ and autodetects schema:

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV dataset.tableName gs://bucket/foldername/something.csv
```

Now I need to make it work together to import all files to respective tables in BQ. If table exists, then replace it. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: AFAIK to load to multiple tables you'll need more of a script. I would use a `*` if I wanted all the files to land in the same table.

Comment: no, that's all is needed. Either sed or xargs or something is needed to do it sequentially. Therer are not so many tables

Comment: Try adding that information to the question - or posting a new one that says what kind of script you want

Answer (score 0):

First, create a file with all the list with all the folders you want to load into BigQuery:

```
gsutil ls "gs://bucket/foldername/*.csv" > allmynicetables.txt
```

Then, create a simple loop to repeat the load operation for every csv file listed on allmynicetables.txt:

```
while read p ; do bq load --autodetect --replace=true --source_format=CSV dataset.tableName $p ; done < allmynicetables.txt
```

Just a couple of clarifications:

`--replace=true` does the trick to overwrite existing table.

Also, I am not sure why you put `dataset.tableName`, are you always copying to the same dataset? Can you extract the desired dataset/table name from the name of your .csv source file? This is not clear to me from your question, please clarify.